# foreach loop error message

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, vsto

Anyone know why the following code:

```
foreach (Word.XMLSchemaReference reference in Globals.ThisDocument.Application.ActiveDocument)
{

}
```

Gives me:

> Error 1   **foreach** statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document' because
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document' does not contain a public
>   definition for 'GetEnumerator'    C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Office\Templates\Projects\Project1\Project1\ActionsPaneControl1.cs    1054    13  Project1

I have that code in an actionpane control in a Word document level project which has been created with VS2013 using C# .Net 4.0 for Word 2010.

I am trying to run the following code within that loop:

```
if (reference.NamespaceURI.Contains("ActionsPane"))
{
reference.Delete();
}
```

Basically, the documents created with my addin give the user a message when they reopen the created document:

> One or more XML expansion packs are available for this file. Choose
>   one from the list below. No XML expansion pack Microsoft Actions Pane
>   3

So it seems I need to find the reference and delete it before the user saves the document?

Comment: This message says that `Globals.ThisDocument.Application.ActiveDocument` isn't an enumerable collection, so you can't enumerate through it with `foreach`

Comment: How would I get around this issue?  I want to `    if (reference.NamespaceURI.Contains("ActionsPane"))
      {
        reference.Delete();
      }`.

Comment: Then updated part of code doesn't matter. The error is in `foreach` statement. The `ActiveDocument` is NOT a collection, so you can't iterate through it - just like you CAN iterate through `List`, but CAN'T iterate through `double`. You need to find a property in `ActiveDocument` class, which contains a collection you need.

Comment: In my answer below - use the ActiveDocument.XMLSchemaReferences collection

Answer (score 1):

The message is very clear: Globals.ThisDocument.Application.ActiveDocument does not implement IEnumerable. I think you are looking for something in the active document that implements a IEnumerable of XMLSchemaReference. Check the properties from the Globals.ThisDocument.Application.ActiveDocument.

Comment: Updated question with purpose of loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to enumerate over ActiveDocument. Are you trying to enumerate over the XML schemas?

```
foreach (var schema In ActiveDocument.XMLSchemaReferences){
    schema.dosomething
}
```

Comment: Updated my question with further much needed details.

Comment: I still think you are trying to enumerate over the wrong thing. Try the above code

Comment: The foreach part now works, but it doesn't have a .delete command to delete any found schemas.

Comment: I'm using Word 2003 and I have a Delete() method on the reference - uppercase D.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong thing, I type `schema.Delete();` and get `Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Delete' and no extension method 'Delete' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)`

Comment: It looks like your schema reference is a generic object type. Try casting it to XMLSchemaReference - ((XMLSchemaReference)schema).Delete() - or change the "var schema" to "XMLSchemaReference schema".

Comment: OK, the code now works, but it still displays `One or more XML expansion packs are available for this file. Choose one from the list below. No XML expansion pack Microsoft Actions Pane 3` when opening the documents created with my action pane.

Comment: why have I just been downvoted for providing an answer?

Comment: Policing peoples comments seems to be an obsession with some people, rather than spending time answering the question.